# unresponsive cooldown (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Currently I'm trying to cooldown my bot commands in javascript.

So I made a little code based on the `discord.js` documentation.

```js
 // cooldowns
const Discord = require ("discord.js");
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection ();
    
if (! cooldowns.has (command.name)) {
    cooldowns.set (command.name, new Discord.Collection ());
}
console.log (1)

const now = Date.now ();
const timestamps = cooldowns.get (command.name);
const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 5) * 1000;

console.log (2)

if (timestamps.has (message.author.id)) {
    const expirationTime = timestamps.get (message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;
console.log (3)
    if (now <expirationTime) {
        const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
        return message.reply (`please wait $ {timeLeft.toFixed (5)} seconds before using this command again.`);
    }
}
console.log (4)

timestamps.set (message.author.id, now);
setTimeout (() => timestamps.delete (message.author.id), cooldownAmount);
console.log (5)
console.log (cooldownAmount);
```

No error appears, and `console.log()` gives: "1245 5000". No matter the order.
This code is placed in an "events" folder, in the `message.js` file.

Comment: is all that just in your index file or inside an event listener?

Comment: This is placed in an event listener.

Comment: You instantiate a new `cooldowns` collection every message, of course it'l never find the cooldown.